# Query database and display result on the same page

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am currently working on spring framework. I have a button on page abc.jsp, that sends a GET request to my controller. The controller calls a method in DAO, and returns a list containing data and forwards it to def.jsp. Is there a way to display the datatable directly on abc.jsp when we click the button. In my research, I found AJAX is a way to do it. I haven't used AJAX before, I'm not sure how to use it as I need to get a list. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached required snippets of my code below. Thanks in advance,

**abc.jsp**

```
<form action="abcd" method="get">
          <button type="submit" onclick="startSpin()">Items in ABCD</button>
</form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("application")
public class ApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    AppDAO AppDAO;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterDataObjectEntityController.class);

    @RequestMapping (value="/abcd",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getItemsInABCD(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest req){
        LOGGER.info("ApplicationController :: ");      
        try {
            map.addAttribute("ItemsInABCDList", AppDAO.getItemsInABCDList());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("ApplicationController :: getItemsInABCDList:: SQLException ::"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return "def"; <-- goes to def.jsp
    }
}
```

**def.jsp**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"
                        id="mytable" style="width: 95%;">

                        <thead>
                            <tr style="font-weight: bold;">

                                <td>col 1</td>
                                <td>col 2</td>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="myvar" items="${ItemsInABCDList}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${myvar.itemNumber}</td>
                                    <td>${myvar.itemName}</td>
                                </tr>

                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mytable= null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    mytable=  $('#mytable').dataTable(
             {
                //columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [0] }]
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "datatable-nosort",
                    orderable: false
                }]
             });

          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Your **getItemsInABCD** is returning string not any list?

Comment: @Pallavi The string it returns is the name of the response page. It is redirected to def.jsp with the return statement. It sends the list as a response to def.jsp using map.addAttribute where getItemsInABCDList() returns a List object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make small changes in your code. If its feasible.
You can use **Javascript** Function to call Axaj Request with either **POST/GET**

call createAjaxRequest function with request Url i.e. abcd and also specify your call-back funtion name i.e. yourCallbackFuncationName

```
createAjaxRequest("abcd",yourCallbackFuncationName);

function createAjaxRequest(requestURL,callbackFuncation){
    var xmlhttp;
    startStopLoader(true);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 ){

            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                try{
                    callbackFuncation(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }catch(e){

                }               
             }

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",requestURL,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   
}

function yourCallbackFuncationName(response) {
        // you can manupulate your list stored in response variable 
        // you can generate your tr/td here and put it back in your main  
          table using innerHTML
}
```

And You need to use @ResponseBody in your java file and return the list of your items. which may look like the below code

```
@RequestMapping (value="/abcd",method=RequestMethod.GET) 
@ResponseBody
    public ItemsInABCDListBean getItemsInABCD(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest req){
        LOGGER.info("ApplicationController :: ");       
        try { 
           ItemsInABCDListBean ItemsInABCDList = AppDAO.getItemsInABCDList();
        } catch (SQLException e) { 
            LOGGER.error("ApplicationController :: getItemsInABCDList:: SQLException ::"+e.getMessage()); 
        } 
        return ItemsInABCDList; // returns List you want to show
    }
```

Hope this will help you. It might be a generic code for your application

Comment: Thank you Pallavi... I shall try this and let you know... I haven't worked on AJAX code before, so I'm finding it a little hard to understand how and where to use it... But i'll go through some tutorials and figure out how to use it. Thanks a lot for the headstart. :)

Comment: Hi Pallavi... I could acheive my desired result.. I returned the list like you said and I created an ajax request to get the response... I found a small snippet of code on the datatables website which helped me put the ajax response into the datatable...And now I can populate the datatable on the same page... Thanks for your time and help... :)